# mvc3 ImageResizer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, path, imageresizer

I downloaded the Nugent ImageResizer and I am trying to resize a picture on upload following an example on this page http://imageresizing.net/docs/managed but I can't seen to put this in a Var or Image variable so i can see it in the **Path.Combine** here is the code

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var changename = getid + "_" + fileName;
          ImageBuilder.Current.Build(changename, changename,
                                                       new ResizeSettings("width=130&height=130"));

            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/profilepic"), changename);
                file.SaveAs(path);
```

How can I get the **ImageBuilder** inside a var or some type of image variable what i would like to do is something like this

```
        var resized=  ImageBuilder.Current.Build(changename, changename,
                                                       new ResizeSettings("width=130&height=130"));
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/profilepic"), resized);
                file.SaveAs(path);
```

all that im trying to do is put the **ImageBuilder** inside the **Path.Combine** without getting an error, any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Why dont you use `WebImage` in `System.Web.Helpers` ?

Comment: I just tried that one but it gives me an error the namespace for this one is _using ImageResizer_

Comment: did you add helpers reference in your project ?

Comment: check [this](http://www.leniel.net/2012/04/resize-img-on-fly-aspnet-webimage.html) to resize images

Comment: yes I put the helpers in the reference thanks for the link i will check that out.

Comment: Why not just pass the final path to ImageResizer first? You should not  try to get an Image or Bitmap instance, as those are not garbage collected, and their .Save() methods have many bugs.

Answer (score 0):

#### ImageResizer should be given the uploaded file and the output path directly

ImageResizer supports both GUIDs and path sanitization. NEVER use the uploaded filename as-is!

```
var i = new ImageJob(file, 
                    "~/uploads/profilepic/<guid>_<filename:A-Za-z0-9>.<ext>", 
                     new ResizeSettings("width=130&height=130&format=jpg"));
i.CreateParentDirectory = true; //Auto-create the uploads directory.
i.Build();

var newVirtualPath = ImageResizer.Util.PathUtils.GuessVirtualPath(i.FinalPath);
```