# How to use ImageResizer in C# .NET/MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

I'm working on a site where I need to crop and resize images that people upload.
I got the code for the upload function but in my httpPost action result I want to resize the image to start off with. I also got the code for that but I can't find a way to show the image.

Here is my code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
{
    if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        foreach (string fileKey in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Keys)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[fileKey];
            if (file.ContentLength <= 0) continue; //Skip unused file controls.

            ImageResizer.ImageJob i = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(file, "~/img/", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings("width=50;height=50;format=jpg;mode=max"));

            i.CreateParentDirectory = true; //Auto-create the uploads directory.
            i.Build();

            string relativePath = "~/img/" + Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName);
            string physicalPath = Server.MapPath(relativePath);
            uploadFile.SaveAs(physicalPath);

            return View((object)relativePath);

    }
}
```

I want go write out the Image information from ImageResizer.ImageJob i..
Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First, the code you're using **allows anybody to upload an executable page and run it**.

Never, *under any circumstances*, should you use `uploadFile.FileName` as part of the final path name, unless you deeply understand path and length sanitization.

Second, ImageJob needs a destination path, not a folder path. You can use variables, like `"~/img/<guid>.<ext>"` and access the resulting physical path from `i.FinalPath`. You can use `ImageResizer.Util.PathUtils.GuessVirtualPath(i.FinalPath)` to get the app-relative path.

As this is almost a precise duplicate of [mvc3 ImageResizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064563/mvc3-imageresizer), please consider using the search feature before posting.